# Lync SDK - Making a plugin for Lync

Tags: .net, sdk, lync, lync-2010

First of all, thanks.

I want to know if there's some example or documentation about how to make a plugin to modify 
(specifically add a kind of input text, like text or emoticons) the Lync 2010. I read the Lync SDK and other documentation related, but i can only found ways of make my own application with Lync properties, not how to modify or add funcionalities to the client itself.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There really isn't a way to modify the Lync client itself, it doesn't have a plugin model. Basically, you've got 2 options:

1. Run the client in [UI Suppression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh345230.aspx) mode, in which case you'll need to implement ALL UI yourself (not great...)
2. Use the API in automation mode, and [dock the conversation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378625.aspx) in a window of your own - in which case you can create any functionality you want to in your own window

From what you said about your application, it sounds like option 2 is the way to go. Roughly speaking, you'd do this:

1. Create your WPF or WinForms window with the buttons you'd need, and a WindowsFormsHost and Panel(WPF) or just a Panel (WinForms) for docking the window
2. Listen out for new conversations using ConversationManager.ConversationAdded
3. Instantiate a new instance of your window, and dock the conversation window into it

Most of this is described in the article I linked to. You could also check out the [Tabbed Conversations application](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26135) for an example of an app that's doing the same thing.

Comment: Excellent, really that i need is transfer some text (encrypted text) with a key for that the other one person get it and decrypt the message. By this option i eliminate the security risk of Lync log and provide some useful characteristic. I think the better UI design is with a window docked. Its something like a game in msn, not?

Comment: This should work fine, then. Actually, you wouldn't necessarily need to dock the conversation window - you could just create a WPF/Winforms app that automates Lync to create a new conversation, and have it post the encrypted text into your conversation. Docking would give it a more integrated feel, but is a little more work